# UILabel's text property without overriding it

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a modal class named `Weather`, this class has a `NSString` property called `degrees` that contains the current weather (in °C degrees).

I have my main viewController caled `MainVC` that has a `UILabel` that presents the current weather, the label is changing dynamiclly according to the `Weather` object's `degrees` property, I want that when the label's text changes, it'll automatically add "**°C**" to the text on the label.

How can I do that without overriding the label's setText: method?

Comment: @Bamsworld I don't know it, can you please explain me how to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the label is currently being set you could do something like -

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°C", degreesFromWeatherObject];
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I haven't thought about it